# How to read integers with sscanf separated by symbols in C?

Tags: c, scanf

so I have a string with the following value

[7, 8]

Now I wan't to store each value (only the numbers) in a 2D array [1][2].
I'm pretty sure using sscanf is the best way to do this, but how do I tell sccanf to only read the integers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2D arrays are usually wrong in C.

Comment: Do you have an *array* containing those values, or a *string* containing `"[7,8]"`?

Comment: `I'm pretty sure using sscanf is the best way to do this`...don't be so sure about that. :-)

Comment: We cannot help much if you don't explain more the input format.

Comment: I recommend adding four spaces in front of every code-like (or input-like) line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sscanf("[%d,%d]", Array[a][b], Array[c][d]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. i used sscanf (string, "[%d,%d]", &array[1,0], &array[1,1])

Answer (score 0):

You might get an entire line using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), or [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) if your system don't have `getline`.

Then you can [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) that line manually. You might indeed at some point use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (and you could use `%n` and always test the return count from `sscanf`), but you could use [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) (its `endptr` argument is handy!), etc.

<sup>*Always* test the return count given by `sscanf`, `fscanf`, `scanf` !</sup>

Some people might recommend [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) which I dislike because it is stateful and non-reentrant.

BTW, 2D arrays are tricky in C (and I recommend avoiding them and use only 1D arrays). You might [dynamically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) allocate some `struct` (that you previously declare) ending with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Answer (score 0):

I don`t if I am understanding your Problem. But I tried.

Quick n dirty. Maybee this help.

```html
for(int i =1; i++; i =< (sizeof(array1D)/arraydatatype) )
{
 array2D[i-1][i-1] = array1D[i-1];
 array2D[i-1][i-1] = array1D[i];
}
```

```html
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < arraysize)
{ array2D [j][0] = array1D [i];
 array2D [j][1] = array1D [i+1];

 j++;
 i+=2; 
}
```

scanf is only for reading from console. But you have already an Array?! If you have a string you can work with strncpy or something..